# Performance issue with NHibernate and Firebird

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, firebird

i have a performance issue with NHibernate 3.3 and Firebird 2.5.1. I created a very simple example with ASP.NET MVC and a local (!) Firebird Database. 
But following Code takes about 1sec for execution ?!?

```
        var startTickCountWrite = Environment.TickCount;

        IRepository<Project> repository = facade.ProjectRepository(null);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 250; ++i)
        {
            var myProject = new Project { ProjectId = i };
            repository.Insert(myProject);
        }
        repository.Commit();

        var endTickCountWrite = Environment.TickCount;
```

If I place the commit() inside the for-loop it takes about 5sec!

Behind Repository and facade is nothing special. I just forward the Project to ISession.Insert.

Project has only ID and ProjectID as properties.

Can anyone tell me whats going wrong?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: So you are doing 250 inserts into an open source database with unknown hardware/memory configuration in one second and you think this is bad?

Comment: _When_ are you connecting the the DBMS? Perhaps the connection is not established until actually needed, so most of this 1 sec might be spent connecting to the DBMS. As for Commit in loop, this is pretty much expected - you are paying the durability price. Transactions need to be ACID, but the "Durability" needs to be enforced only at the transaction's end. So physical IO to the disk may be postponed after the apparent SQL statement execution and actually done in the background, while your transaction is processing other statements. You are defeating that if your transactions are too granular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

250 objects in 1 second does not sound shockingly slow. For evaluating performance it would also be good to provide some comparison - how long does it take to execute the same amount of SQL directly against Firebird?

NHibernate can in some circumstances batch INSERT statements, but I don't know if this works on Firebird. http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-batch-updates The choice of identity generator can also have an effect. Some generators force NHibernate to execute the INSERT statement immediately, which will prevent the use of batching.

From a design point of view you might want to change some things:
IRepository.Insert() is typically named Add(), since it mimics a collection interface (and Insert on collections, if present, usually take an index parameter which is not relevant here of course). Also, Commit() seems out-of-place on the repository, since you will typically have multiple repository instances involved, that share the same transaction and session.

For accurate time measurements, you can use Stopwatch from System.Diagnostics, so you don't need to convert the value yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First i was shocked about 1sec for 250 inserts. But with several other tests it seems to be ok. Thanks for your hints about the design.